# Where can I find the source for the Android “Home screen"

Tags: android, homescreen

I want to learn how the "home screen" implemented. Any idea with what .java files to start?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's referred to as `Launcher`, but you'll not be easily able to compile the stock launcher in Eclipse because it uses some APIs that aren't publicly available. (Go figure.) The code is in `Launcher.java` (in Eclipse, <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> and type `Launcher`), or you can view it online [here](http://www.java2s.com/Open-Source/Android/android-platform-apps/Launcher/com/android/launcher/Launcher.java.htm).